# Using a public coffee grinder for pessach?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover

I'd love to buy some black whole bean coffee which as I understand would not need a kosher certification. Some stores (like Costco) only sell unflavored whole bean coffee. Can I use their grinders to grind whole bean coffee to be used on pessach?

Thanks!

Comment: You're saying if the only thing they sell is unflavored, then the grinder there presumably won't have been used with anything else? Makes sense, but ... a simple problem is if they sell decaf beans; some decaffeination processes use alcohol that's grain-derived. (The rule of thumb is "any plan *yes-caffeine* coffee"...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rabbi Binyomin Forst, in his sefer ["The Kosher Kitchen"](https://www.artscroll.com/Details.aspx?itemNo=9781422608975) explains (Chapter 15: Kashering for Pesach, p. 397):

> A coffee mill used exclusively for plain nonflavored coffee and not washed with chametz may be used on Pesach, if it is thoroughly cleaned.

Link to free excerpt, see [here](https://artscroll.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/kosher-kitchen_ch-15.pdf)

So, according to Rabbi Forst, only if it involves unflavored, plain coffee, and if the mill is not washed with chametz, that should be fine.

***Disclaimer:** I advise you to CYLOR, consult your local Rabbi.*